# What set does this bag belong to? Black, grey, orange, and blue rubber band

Tags: set-identification

Code on bag is 5 number 127S
bricks are black, grey and a few orange
Contains small flat white box 6049725 which contains blue magic sand

Comment: Hi Nata, can you please [add a photo](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) of the bag or its contents? Especially the "blue magic sand" would be of interest, as I can't think of anything clearly fitting that description.

Comment: 6049725 contains a blue rubber band. I think ‘sand’ is a typo by the OP.

Comment: Nata, we need a picture. Also, the seal code 127S either misses the last digit, or has some digits transposed (e.g. 12S7).

Answer (score 7):

Based on the colors in the bag, the potential date code of 12S7 (you wrote 127S but I assume that is a transposition error in your post), and the fact that there is a box with blue rubber bands in it (box number [6049725](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6049725)) I am going out on a limb and suggest this is set [75102 Poe Dameron’s X-wing Fighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75102-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from 2015. The seal code points to a 2017 production date which is possible, as this set was still being sold all the way up to early 2018. It has 5 bags (so having a bag marked 5 fits) and the 5th bag does contain both rubber bands as well as black, grey and orange pieces.

[image]

Comment: The research you did is quite impressive. I think we might not even need to have a picture to confirm now.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. Hope you are right. My box did in fact contain blue powder which are perished rubber bands.  Really appreciate your research.